# zscaler certificate issue

Tags: certificates, oracle-linux

Do any one have idea what could be error reason and how it can be resolved?

```
[root@Linux ~]$ wget https://www.google.com
--2018-10-19 07:46:25--  https://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com... 64.233.177.106, 64.233.177.99, 64.233.177.105, ...
Connecting to www.google.com|64.233.177.106|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.google.com’s certificate, issued by “/C=US/ST=California/O=Zscaler Inc./OU=Zscaler Inc./CN=Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscalertwo.net)/emailAddress=support@zscaler.com”:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer’s authority.
To connect to www.google.com insecurely, use ‘--no-check-certificate’.
[root@Linux ~]$
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use `wget --no-check-certificate` to get pages, as in:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://www.google.com
```

A network equipment/(trasparent?)proxy/firewall is messing up with your requests.

For further data, talk with your local networking guys.

Another approach is asking the networking guys for the zscaler root CA, and installing it in your Linux. Again the same recommendation, talk with them.

Comment: Thanks !! I already tried earlier with --no-check-certificate and it was working but i don't want to go with this as it's not recommended and good approach. Need permanent fix will be much appreciated. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: The "permanent fix" is going via a VPN or asking your networking guys for a network that does not go via the ZScaler. I think you do not understood it is your networking guys that mess up with SSL/TLS on purpose. As I said, it makes more sense talking with your networking guys than a bunch of strangers.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I fixed it without networking team guys.